# Get distinct record in table A based on an incrementing status value in Table B

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: one with MAINTENANCE REQUESTS, and one that holds the STATUS for the specific request. The idea is, that the users can follow the STATUS update trail.

I'm looking for a query:

- Retrieve all MAINTENANCE RECORDS with a STATUS higher than 1, but less than 1000.

As of now, what started playing around with is this:

```
select distinct mr.*
     , mrsl.request_status
     , mrsl.date_applied
     , mrsl.changed_by 
  from maintenance_request mr
 inner 
  join maintenance_request_status_log mrsl 
    on mrsl.request_id = mr.id
 order 
    by mr.id desc
     , mrsl.request_status desc
```

... but this gives me one records per status entry, of course. Im not sure how to acheive my two queries? Anyone?

As per the image, only two records would be shown: ID 7 is OK, and ID 6 should only show the record with request_status 3 (the highest one).

/Bob

Comment: Add the `Where` clause filter on your query for the `request_status`.

Comment: so you need distinct values or not?to be more clear add sample of raw data and expected result please

Comment: I need distinct. For example, if I have one MAINTENANCE RECORD with three status updates (entries), for example 1,2,1000 then it should not be shown. But if has not had an entry with value 1000 (which means COMPLETE), is should be retrieved, but only ONCE, not once per STATUS entry.

Comment: (updated the question, one query is enough i think)

Comment: Added image and additional description.

Comment: there is no image in your post

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this does the trick:

```
select mr.*, (select request_status from maintenance_request_status_log where request_id = mr.id order by id desc limit 1) as status from maintenance_request mr
```